# Using JeroMQ over TCP, is there a way to get a sender's IP?

Tags: java, tcp, zeromq, jeromq

Our application is using JeroMQ 0.4.3 to send messages between a client application and an API. (using curve encryption with ZAuth).

We're getting client messages from a **`ROUTER`** socket in our broker (MDP pattern).

What's the best way to find the sender's IP when receiving a message in the broker?

In ZeroMQ, it seems it might be possible using **`ZMQ_SRCFD`** message option and **`getpeername()`** but I have not found a way to translate that to JeroMQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The more recent ZeroMQ API indeed defines **`ZMQ_SRCFD`** property a message may carry.

**Fact A)**
one is principally never sure, what ZeroMQ API version ( 2.x ~ 3.x ~ 4.2.2 ~ ? *as of EoY-2017* ) does the remote system use, unless some indeed rigid and intrusion-robust version-enforcement policy is put in place and active.

**Fact B)**
recent ZeroMQ API defines for **`tcp://`** transport-class this:

> **`ZMQ_SRCFD`**
>     Returns the file descriptor of the socket the message was read from. This allows application to retrieve the remote endpoint via **`getpeername(2)`**. Be aware that the respective socket might be **closed** already, **reused** even. Currently only implemented for TCP sockets.

**Fact C)**
Any language wrapper or binding, including one's preferred JeroMQ or other, has to cover the selected scope ( be it a full or a partial scope-coverage ) on its own.

If one lacks a feature in some particular language port/binding version, the best next step is to assess a feasibility of extending the published source code, so as to also cover a wished feature by (re)-implementing the language port/binding so as to best meet the desired API feature as specified by the ZeroMQ published specification.

**Fact D)**
In cases, where C) gets unfeasible or incomplete as per principal uncertainty expressed under B) , one may still proceed to rather implement one's own, high level IP-address node-(re)-discovery strategy, based on any suitable grade of security-concerns, starting from even a { naive self-declaration | two-step IP-validation | ... | a trust-less IP-validation }-protocol, if one needs it.